Multiple characters for same pinyin （拼音） and finding out what tone from hanzi （汉字）

Are there multiple hanzi characters for the same pinyin transcription in any case?
Is there some trick to finding out what tone a hanzi character is without the pinyin?


There are about 400 Pinyin combinations of initials and finals, about 1100 if further combined with a tone. But there are about 6,000 Chinese characters. Therefore, there must be many homophones (like male and mail, 医生 and 一生)


Are there multiple hanzi characters for the same pinyin transcription in any case?

Yes, you are right.
For example:
她，他，它，踏，塔，塌，等等的发音都是ta，但是他们的音调(tone)不一样，有的是一声，有的是二声，有的是三声，有的是四声。音调(tone)一共有4个，分别是一声，二声，三声，四声。

Is there some trick to finding out what tone a hanzi character is without the pinyin?

There is no cut corners, the only way to learn Chinese is extensively reading.
Tone is not important to know which one word they say. Important is 情景 and pronounce.
Just like a "word" in English, different context have different meaning, but in one 情景 you can according to 情景 and pronounce know about(大概) which one word they say.
一声的声音最轻，四声的声音最重，如果你想(或愿意)的话都可以读作一声或者二声，普通话中有一个词语叫做轻声细语。

Actually, it should be exist 5 tones,  https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E8%BC%95%E8%81%B2

@James  哈哈, 有意思. 但是小学语文课本上说只用4个音调. 这点我还是比较确认的, link that you provide https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E8%BC%95%E8%81%B2 say:  "轻声（neutral tone）是汉语中所具有的一种特殊变调现象（多见于现代标准汉语）。轻声一般不被当作声调看待，因为它没有固定的调值。 "

@James  Correct: 只用4个音调 ---> 只有4个音调

It depends on whether your education system teaches 注音 (as in Taiwan) or 拼音 (as in Mainland).

@r13 I see that 拼音 in OP's question and pinyin in both OP's question and the tag of question.

The user @James has cited the 繁體版 of the same material you cited but in 簡體 (it contains both versions). From that, I assume he was taught with 注音 and 繁體字 rather than 拼音 and 簡體字.

@r13 我感觉你的思维没有理清。首先，如我之前的评论所说的那样，我的这个答案回答的是关于简体中文，拼音(原始问题中包含了 汉字，拼音，问题标签中有pinyin)。 其次，不管是中国还是台湾，亦或者是任何其他说中文的人，看维基百科上关于中文声调都是看 https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E8%BC%95%E8%81%B2 这个链接相关，相关指的是从这个链接进去，可能会显示不同的方式，有的选择简体中文，有的选择新加坡简体，有的选择台湾正体等等，但无一例外，轻声的页面里都说了这样一句话：“轻声（neutral tone）是汉语中所具有的一种特殊变调现象（多见于现代标准汉语）。轻声一般不被当作声调看待，因为它没有固定的调值。 ”，前面这句加粗显示，意味着：在中文发音中，音调只有4个，尽管 User: James 可能确实看的是台湾版。

I was commenting on your response to @james' comment, and pointing out that the differences of opinions are mainly due to the difference between the two systems. I wasn't commenting on your answer to the OP's question then.

@r13 I see. 但是我刚刚想表达的是，根据维基百科的这个链接 https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E8%BC%95%E8%81%B2 里所写的，可以得出：不管是中国大陆，还是台湾，亦或者是新加坡，在中文世界里，轻声不被认为是一个声调。所以音调只有4个，如果说音调有5个的话，可能没有认真阅读维基百科上关于轻声的解释。

I don't know who was the author and the system he was based on for the writing, but I am aware the same article provided both 繁體 and 簡體 for the readers.  I don't want to get into the argument, only to point out to you that it is quite obvious that @james has read the one with 繁體 and made a comment on your answer reflecting his learning. I think we shall end this non-productive conservation here.

@r13 OK. I see.

@Tom 無論您認不認同有五聲調；實際與漢人的對話中，您就是有使用到它！ 請試著說出不含輕聲的 : 謝謝 , 我們, 官大人 , 難相處 & 爺爺, 奶奶, 爸爸, 媽媽, 公公, 婆婆, 伯伯, 叔叔, 姑姑, 舅舅, 哥哥, 姐姐, 弟弟, 妹妹 ...etc. 不便扭嗎

@James  中国大陆语文课本上说只有4个音调，维基百科上也说了 "轻声一般不被当作声调看待，因为它没有固定的调值。"，你就说句你搞错了或者看错了，这也没什么大不了的吧？另外音调在实际谈话中也没那么重要，大多数人在交谈时也没人在意你的音调是否准确吧？

yeap, 我搞错了或者看错了 +1

大多数人在交谈时也没人在意你的音调是否准确吧, 因為 你在同溫層,身邊不存在音調不正確的人,自然不需要去更正誰的音調；我跟音調不準確的外國朋友對話，就會去更正人家的音調!

@James  理解了，所处情况不同吧。

@Tom 也許身處情況不同吧，我身邊是有外籍勞工的，即使是菲律賓人. 英語腔調與我們的英語也是有差異；若英文已無法溝通,中文再因腔調問題無法溝通 就真的雞同鴨講了, 所以我會及時糾正他們的音調,儘可能避免日後溝通問題.

@James 如果英语都学不好，汉语就更难学好了。请注意防范缅甸，菲律宾，柬埔寨等东南亚地区的诈骗， KK园区 建议你了解一下。

@Tom 也是音調的問題，像是菲律賓人說 "What sons"... 搞半天才知道人家說的原來是 "Watsons" @@", 所以 還是堅持 請它們學好中文!  避免出現連英文都無法溝通的狀況


Are there multiple hanzi characters for the same pinyin transcription in any case?

Absolute, there are exise lots of hanzi characters using the same pinyin.
Even the same hanzi character exist different pinyin for different situation.
So complicate!?

Is there some trick to finding out what tone a hanzi character is without the pinyin?

If you can copy these hanzi characters, then paste these into :
https://translate.google.com.tw/?sl=zh-TW&tl=en&text=%E8%81%B2%E8%AA%BF&op=translate
You can found that there exise a speak icon under the hanzi characters.
Now, turn on your speaker, and press the icon, and Enjoy.
